# Summing raster files through GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, osgeo4w, summarizing

I have a folder with over 500 raster (.tif) files. I want to produce an output raster file that is the sum of all the raster files in my folder. I am trying to use `gdal` and sepcifically the `gdal_calc` command to carry this action out, but I am encountering an error message where the output file is just not recognized. Here is what I am doing:

I open OSGeo4W Shell. I see the following message:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
run o-help for a list of available commands
C:\>
```

I then navigate to my directory using `cd`

I then run simply `gdalinfo --version` to make sure gdal is installed and ready and receive:

```
GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19
```

I then run simply `gdal_calc` to make sure the command is recognized and receive:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
Usage: gdal_calc.py --calc=expression --outfile=out_filename [-A filename]
                    [--A_band=n] [-B...-Z filename] [other_options]
```

followed by a long list of options. All of this tells me that everything should be running as it should so far, or at least I think so.

I then run the following code to sum all the raster files in my target folder, and produce an output raster called "result.tif":

```
for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc -A %f -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B
```

This produces the following error message for each iteration, an output error message for each raster file in my target folder (where "X" indicates the specific input raster file):

```
C:\Users\MyName\Path\to\My\Folder>gdal_calc -A Input_Raster_X.tif -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
ERROR 4: result.tif: No such file or directory
No such file or directory: 'result.tif'
```

And so I get this message over 500 times, one for each input raster file. I am confused about this error message because it says it cannot find the file or directory called "result.tif", but why would it be able to find this? It doesn't exist yet. It is the output raster file I am trying to ultimately produce. How might I fix this error so that I can sum all of the raster files together and produce the intended output raster file that is that sum?

Comment: You've sort of answered your own question - result.tif doesn't exist, so you need to create result.tif first. Remember that it's not just an output raster, it's also an input raster:

`gdal_create -if Input_Raster_1.tif -burn 0 result.tif`

Comment: That makes sense then that I would need to create a blank raster first. So then first I would run: `gdal_create -if Input_Raster_1.tif -burn 0 result.tif` to create the blank raster, and then I would run: `for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc -A %f -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B` to create my intended sum raster? I tried running your suggestion, but received: `'gdal_create' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`, and the same message when simply running: `gdal_create`. Do you know why it might not be getting recognized?

Comment: Update: I did a workaround and just made a blank raster in QGIS, not sure if the extent will match up, but the code is now running I see, and my rasters appear to be being added up. I see `0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 .. 90 .. 100 - Done` after each iteration, so I assume this is working, but I will of course need to wait a bit for this to process to see if it's actually a sum of all the rasters that is produced.

Comment: Update: The processing finished, and I looked at the output raster and it is not what I was looking for, it just looks like a single one of the raster inputs, not like they were all added together, since the output raster is just white and black, with just 2 values, when there should be many.

Comment: You have too old GDAL for using gdal_create. It does not exist in version 2.2.4. It is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_create.html `New in version 3.2.0.`.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to use image `result.tif` both for reading and writing at the same time. Try to add renaming into your script `--outfile=temp_result.tif` then delete the old result.tif and rename the temporary one.

Comment: That's a good suggestion about the renaming. I didn't realize my version of gdal was outdated. Though I came up with a workaround, by just making my own blank raster file in QGIS and using that. So now the code works, but there is a major problem. Rather than summing the raster files together, creating a raster `.tif` that has many shades of values, it's as if the whole output raster is masked by the last raster file in the summing order, so just revealing to values, black and white, in the output raster. Do you know if I might have my gdal_calc syntax wrong?